# jquery setting value to dropdown

Tags: jquery, dwr

I have a dropdown with list of values loaded using dwr call. I fetch data from db say I have a location called India. I use

```
$('select[name="cname"]').find(
'option:contains("'
+ data.loc + '")')
.attr("selected", true);
```

to make it selected. cname is the dropdown name. data.loc is the data i fetch from db. The problem here is if i have two locations like India and Indiana, it iterates and set both values as selected with the recent value(Indiana) being set. The actual value to be set is India. Only if i select Indiana it has to be selected and not for India. Is there any option to fix this?

Comment: First thing why you are using contains, Why cannot you check equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to apply the custom filter match the elements return by selector.

```
$('select[name="cname"] option').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == data.loc; 
}).attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `val()`

```
$('select[name="cname"]').val(data.loc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Equals Selecter.Please refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not a check for the equality:

```
if($(this).val() == data.loc){
    $('select[name="cname"] option[value="' + data.loc + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can done it by `Val()`, Try like below it will help you..

```
$('select[name="cname"]').val(data.loc);
alert($("select[name='cname'] option:selected").text());
```